# sql like javascript library to work with arrays and objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv

I have to mess around with several csv files in node, to produce new csv files (selecting, joining, grouping, etc).

It's fairly easy to accomplish it all with lodash's functions, but it all tends to be very verbose, and not so nice to maintain.

It could all be solved with a clear, nice, readable, self-documenting, sql statement.

So I'm looking for a library that would allow me to work with a couple of arrays of objects, treat them like tables, apply a sql statement, and get the resulting array ob objects.

Is there something like that?

Comment: You could read them into a mongodb and use mongoose

Comment: csv  files are comma separated value files so if you simply run string.split(","); it gives you an array of all the data why do you need a library?

Comment: Or you could use json documents rather then csv.

Comment: I have no trouble parsing and writing csv files. The thing is I have to combine several of them with operations like select, join, group, sum, average, etc, that could be easily accomplished with a few sql statements, but doing the same with javascript is pretty tiresome....

Comment: taffyDB comes to mind. or feed sqlLite your csv and go nuts.

Answer (score 2):

Yes of course. As the saying goes, there are 1000 ways to skin a cat.
Have a look at the following libraries.

http://www.jinqjs.com
https://linqjs.codeplex.com

Here's an example query:

```
var people = [
              {Name: 'Jane', Age: 20, Location: 'Smithtown'},
              {Name: 'Ken', Age: 57, Location: 'Islip'},
              {Name: 'Tom', Age: 10, Location: 'Islip'}
            ];

var population = [
              {Location: 'Islip', People: 123},
              {Location: 'Melville', People: 332},
            ];

var result = new jinqJs()
    .from(people)
    .leftJoin(population)
      .on( function( left, right ) {
        return (left.Location === right.Location);
      } )
    .where( function(row) {
      return ( row.Age > 15);
    })
    .select('Name', 'Location', 'People');
```

Comment: There is no need to this library with ES5-6: [JavaScript equivalents of some common LINQ methods](https://gist.github.com/DanDiplo/30528387da41332ff22b)